0.76.3 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36611
I tried everything here, but it didn't work for me.
People have experienced issues while upgrading React Native to a newer version, but I haven't done an upgrade. The problem occurs after version 0.71, but I don't know what to do I only upgraded to Xcode 16
Podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported

# Prepare React Native project
prepare_react_native_project!

# Framework linkage configuration
linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

# Main target configuration
target 'yourappname' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  # Use frameworks with static linkage
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  
  # Use React Native settings
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Specify the absolute path to the application root
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # Tests target configuration
  target 'yourappnameTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

# Post-installation configurations
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Exclude arm64 architecture for iPhone Simulator
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
    end
  end
end

npx react-native-info
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
  OS: macOS 14.5
  CPU: (12) arm64 Apple M2 Pro
  Memory: 61.25 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.20.4
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.4/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 10.9.1
    path: ~/node_modules/.bin/npm
  Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.16.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 24.1
      - iOS 18.1
      - macOS 15.1
      - tvOS 18.1
      - visionOS 2.1
      - watchOS 11.1
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
  Xcode:
    version: 16.1/16B40
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.10
    path: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli":
    installed: 15.0.1
    wanted: 15.0.1
  react:
    installed: 18.3.1
    wanted: 18.3.1
  react-native:
    installed: 0.76.3
    wanted: 0.76.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: true
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: true

package.json
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^7.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^7.1.8",
    "axios": "^1.7.8",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1286.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.21.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.14.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.9.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^6.8.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.3",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },


The current version is as follows, and now it finds the RCTAppDelegate.h file, but the RCTBridgeDelegate.h file is still not found. Updating the Podfile like this was enough for me.
podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

  platform :ios, '15.1'
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'yourAppName' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAppDelegate', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/AppDelegate'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'



  


  use_react_native!(
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'YourAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
    end
  end
end



  


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
